# How can I create four columns from this 2d list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, arraylist

I'm new into python and pandas and I'm having hard time transforming this 2d list into four independent columns, I'm getting two columns with more than one data for every record. May be I created it the wrong way? I don't know.

Please help me out, I'm trying to make results look like this:
[These are the columns that I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPwZW.png)

And
[This is what I have done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2JeH.png)

THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
results = [[('three', 'beer'), ('zero', 'wine')], [('one', 'beer'), ('two', 'wine')]]
Player1Qty = []
Player1type = []
Player2Qty = []
Player2type = []
for tmp in results:
    Player1Qty.append(tmp[0][0])
    Player1type.append(tmp[0][1])
    Player2Qty.append(tmp[1][0])
    Player2type.append(tmp[1][1])
pd.DataFrame({'Player1Qty': Player1Qty, 'Player1type': Player1type, 'Player2Qty': Player2Qty, 'Player2type': Player2type})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


data = [
        [('one', 'apple'), ('three', 'orange') ],
        [('two', 'pear'), ('four', 'banana') ]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
out = pd.DataFrame([*df.apply(np.hstack, axis=1)])
cols = [f'Player{i//2 + 1}{"Qty" if i % 2 else "type"}' for i in out.columns]
out.columns = cols
print(out)
>>>

    Player1type Player1Qty  Player2type Player2Qty
0   one         apple       three       orange
1   two         pear        four        banana
```